# Ferris wheel type structure b2revolutejoint

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a ferris wheel type object with carts connected to it using `b2revolute` joints. When the ferris wheel turns, I want the joints to be able to spin freely so the carts always face the right way.

I tried to set a motor on the joint to constantly rotate the carts opposite to the way the wheel is moving, however this just spins the carts all the way around no matter how slowly I turn them.

Is there an easier way to allow the carts to remain the correct way when I rotate the ferris wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way about to build a Ferris Wheel is:

1. The support legs (if you do ones) should be a static body with fixtures set as sensors. otherwise the carts will not be able to rotate through them.
2. The wheel it self should be a dynamic circular(your choice, can be other shape) body attached to the legs with b2revolute joint.
3. The cart should be attached to the wheel with b2Wheel joints. Set frequancy somewhere between 6 and 8 ( you need to have a play with that to find a sweet spot ).

Here is a link to an example how you can achieve the goal:

[Ferris Wheel example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t2l5hc81xydwa4/box2dFerrieWheel.zip)

I have made an example in RUBE Box2D editor. I don't know what you use, so I have also exported it as a C++ code and JSON format.

I hope it is what you are looking for.